# How to solve 'incompatible input shape' error when calling Keras model.predict()?

Tags: keras, neural-network, predict

**Error message on dimensions when calling keras.model.predict()**

I created a neuronal network model using Keras from tensorflow 22.3.1

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Dense(24, input_shape=(48,), activation="relu"))
model1.add(Dense(24, activation="relu"))
model1.add(Dense(4,  activation="linear"))
model1.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=sgd(learning_rate=0.01))
```

here is the summary of the model by the way

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense_33 (Dense)            (None, 24)                1176      
                                                                 
 dense_34 (Dense)            (None, 24)                600       
                                                                 
 dense_35 (Dense)            (None, 4)                 100       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,876
Trainable params: 1,876
```

when executing a prediction of the model

```
model1.predict(np.array([48]))[0]
```

I get the following error

```
WARNING : tensorflow : Model was constructed with shape (None, 48) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 48), dtype=tf.float32, name='dense_33_input'), name='dense_33_input', description="created by layer 'dense_33_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None,).

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_11' (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "dense_33" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_11' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=int32)
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

Any advice to solve the issue ? Thank you in advance

I tried to understand the input shape issue with the following program

```
x = tf.ones((48,))
y = model1(x)
```

I expected to initialize the model by providing the weights as indicated in the following blog
[text](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/)

It resulted in a similar error

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_7' (type Sequential).
Input 0 of layer "dense_21" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (48,)
Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_7' (type Sequential):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(48,), dtype=float32)
  • training=None
  • mask=None
```

Additionally I tried to reshape the input vector with

```
X = np.array([48])
model1.predict(X.reshape(1,48))
```

and resulted in `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (1,48)`

Consequently I changed the entry input with

```
X = np.array([1,48])
model1.predict(X)
```

and resulted in `ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_11" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 48), found shape=(None, 2)`

Comment: sorry I just noticed that my array was smaller than 48 elements. and it seems to work when the array is correctly sized.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about arrays in general.

The first array you created: `X = np.array([48])` has only one element which is 48, because you created it from a list with only one element: `[48]`. Therefore, you cannot reshape it to the shape `(1, 48)` because that shape includes 48 elements, the number of elements don't match.

The second array you created: `X = np.array([1,48])` was of shape `(None, 2)` once it was passed to `model1.predict()` because you created it with a list that has two elements, 1 and 48.

To correctly create an array with the right shape consider using methods such as `np.full((48,), x)`, it will create an array with one dimension, 48 elements all with a value of x which you can define earlier.
alternatively, you can create a list iteratively and pass it to `np.array()`

Good luck, Hope I could help!